# Laravel 5.0 display item from array where the value of a key matches a value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => {#354 ▼
    +"id": 38
    +"block_newsletter_id": 102
    +"item_type": "title"
    +"html_key": ""
    +"content": "TITLE"
    +"properties": ""
  }
  1 => {#355 ▼
    +"id": 39
    +"block_newsletter_id": 102
    +"item_type": "text"
    +"html_key": ""
    +"content": "Some text. Hey."
    +"properties": ""
  }
  2 => {#356 ▼
    +"id": 40
    +"block_newsletter_id": 102
    +"item_type": "button"
    +"html_key": ""
    +"content": "click here"
    +"properties": ""
  }
]
```

Now I send this array to my view and my goal is to show the content of the item_type "title" in my h1 tag.

I can do it like this:

```
@foreach($blockItemsContent as $blockItemContent)
    @if($blockItemContent->item_type == 'title')
        <h1>{{ $blockItemContent->content }}</h1>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

But if I want to put my item_type text in a p tag I need to do the same. Isn't there a better more efficient way than having to write multiple for each loops?

Comment: Where does this array come from? Why not structure your data properly?

Comment: @NicoHaase from my controller, how should it be structured then?

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare something like this array in you controller's method and send it to the view:

```php
$titleItemTypeContent = [];
foreach ($blockItemsContent as $blockItemContent)
{
    if ($blockItemContent->item_type == 'title')
        $titleItemTypeContent[] = [$blockItemContent->id, $blockItemContent->content];
}
```

and reuse `$titleItemTypeContent` in the blade as many times as you wish.

Comment: The problem is I have multiple $blockItemsContent becasue I have a block that has it own blockItemsContent and I have multiple blocks

Comment: You can use some key for `$titleItemTypeContent` to identify your content

Answer (score 0):

You can make group of each type of your types in your controller like:

```
collect($blockItemsContent)->groupBy('item_type');
```

and pass it to view and you have your types.

Comment: How can I acces my title then for example? I tried this: {{ $blockItemsContent->title->content }}

Answer (score 0):

As per your question 
If item_type = title then display in h1 tag
If item_type = text then display in p tag

Others are display in span tag

In blade file :

```
@foreach($blockItemsContent as $item)
     @if($item->item_type == 'title')
         <h1>{{ $item->content }}</h1>
     @elseif($item->item_type == 'text')
         <p>{{ $item->content }}</p>
     @else
          <span>{{$item->content}}</span>
     @endif
@endforeach
```